# Using columns as cell values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Transposing/Bringing my DF into a new form.

```
DF =
   Id music_item playlist_owner                playlist                entity_name
0   0   tune 6-9       my 14-15  elrow Guest List 17-32                        O O
1   1        O O  leticia 28-34      animal humor 36-47  157 Riverside Avenue 4-23
```

into

```
DF =
   Id     Goal            Loc
0   0    music_item      tune 6-9    
1   0    playlist_owner  my 14-15
2   0    playlist        elrow Guest List 17-32
3   1    entity_name     157 Riverside Avenue 4-23
4   1    playlist_owner  leticia 28-34
5   1    playlist        animal humor 36-47
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I can't really replicate your dataframe because of the way you posted it, but the below will get you what you need.

Assuming your dataframe is called df, you can use `pd.melt()` and rename the columns afterwards:

```
new_df = pd.melt(df,id_vars='Id')    
new_df.columns = ['Id','Goal','Loc']
```

which prints:

```
new_df
Out[59]: 
   Id            Goal                     Loc
0   0      music_item                tune 6-9
1   1      music_item                     O O
2   0  playlist_owner                my 14-15
3   1  playlist_owner           leticia 28-34
4   0        playlist  elrow Guest List 17-32
5   1        playlist      animal humor 36-47
6   0     entity_name                     O O
7   1     entity_name             Avenue 4-23
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you :)